# Просмотр pdf на сайте

Tags: php, javascript

Суть, необходимо на сайте выводить pdf. Тобишь онлайн просмотр pdf файла на сайте.
Как реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так

```
<object data="you_link_to.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="90%" height="450px">
    <a href="you_link_to.pdf">Download PDF file</a>
</object>
```